# Display all Ghost tags

Tags: ghost

I would like to add all my tags to a footer section. `{{tags}}` seems to only work within a post, but not somewhere in the default template.

How can I display a full list of all tags created?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my result using the [Ghost API](https://themes.ghost.org/docs/ghost-api-ajax), however I would be surprised if this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `get` helper:

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
    <ul class="tags">
        {{#foreach tags}}
            <li>
                <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
            </li>
        {{/foreach}}
    </ul>
{{/get}}
```

You can read more about `get` helper on [docs](https://themes.ghost.org/docs/get).